# Error using Auth0’s Node/Hapi Quickstart

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, auth0

I've downloaded the Node/Hapi quickstart at: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/hapi with my pre-filled in data.

I am able to run the node server and access the `/public` endpoint. When I try to access the `/private` endpoint (via POSTMAN), I get the following error:

```
{
  "statusCode": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Missing authentication"
}
```

In order to obtain an access token, I POST a request to `https://<My Account>.auth0.com/oauth/ro` with the following payload:

```
{
    "client_id":   "<My Client ID>",
    "username":    "<My Username>",
    "password":    "<My Password>",
    "connection":  "Username-Password-Authentication",
    "grant_type":  "password",
    "scope":       "openid name email"
}
```

which returns a response containing my access token:

```
{
    "id_token": <Id Token>,
    "access_token": <Access Token>,
    "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

I now try hit the `/private` endpoint passing in the Authorization header with my access token as follows:

```
GET /private HTTP/1.1
Host: <My Machine Name>:8000
Authorization: Bearer <Access Token>
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 87dd4307-2a1c-b36e-0377-129cf60b676d
```

Which returns the following error:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Bad HTTP authentication header format"
}
```

I've tried a lot of things but am unable to get beyond this point. ANY help would be appreciated.

**Environment Specs:**

- Node v6.5.0
- Npm v3.10.6
- hapi: ^15.1.1
- hapi-auth-jwt: ^4.0.0

Thanks,
Genaro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're doing things **exactly** how it's described in the question, the issue is that you need to pass the received `id_token` when calling your `/private` endpoint instead of the `access_token`.

This is mentioned in point 4. of the quickstart you're following:

> You can now make requests against your secure API by providing the Authorization header in your requests with a **valid JWT id_token**.

For a more in-depth look to the different kinds of tokens used throughout Auth0 authentication system you should read [Tokens used by Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens).

Comment: This fixed the issue. I know for a fact that I tried this before posting, but I think I had another issue on my server side code that was also a problem. Thank you.